# Moved a site to GCP, now my flash object doesn't render properly

Tags: flash

I recently moved a site to GCP.  Once a year, we do a Christmas fundraiser where users can purchase ornaments to decorate a Christmas scene.  This scene is a flash object that reads an xml file that holds the users decorations.  The flash object isn't rendering properly.  It's not suppressing things marked as not-visible in the xml file, for one.  I still have the old site running and it works there.  Is there anything about hosting on the GCP that would prevent something from serving properly?

198.91.86.125/christmastree/tree_2008.htm is the old site and you can see the functionality
tarheeloesrescue.org/christmastree/tree_2008.htm the new site and see the 'broken' state.

Answer (score 1):

Contents of

http://198.91.86.125/christmastree/tree.xml

is different from

http://tarheeloesrescue.org/christmastree/tree.xml

are they not supposed to be the same if you lifted and shifted the website?

Comment: tree.xml is what drives the visibility and behavior of the decorations.  The contents from the old is last years' set of decorations.  I reverted to that and get expected behavior, so at least that narrows it down to the new xml file.  The process that generates it is the same, so I will look down that route.

Comment: seems to work now, did you the change file on GCP? If so the issue must be in the xml file, not google cloud platform.

Comment: Turns out I need better user input checking.  They had entered a character that broke the XML.